# Scrolling background with raphael js

Tags: javascript, background, raphael

I'm trying to use Raphael.js to make a little game, and I want the game to have a scrolling background so that it seems infinite.  I made the background with a Raphael object:

```
var paper = new Raphael($('#canvas'), 0, 0);
var c = paper.image("sky.jpg", 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
paper.setSize(1000,1000);
```

but I can't seem to actually move the image by it's x coordinates or even re-draw the image.  I tried:

```
paper._left = -2000;
c.attrs.x = -2000;
paper.image("sky.jpg", -2000, 0, 1000, 1000);
var d = document.getElementById('canvas');
d.left = -2000;
```

and I can't get it to move.  I just want to put this statement in some kind of loop so that it will continually decrement the X coordinate or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.attr()` method provided by Raphael instead.

Use can pass in an object instead, as you might want to set at least both `x` and `y` values for this.

```
c.attr({
    x: -2000
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/EmGeE/

Reference: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the paper (not without moving everything). So to make a scrolling background you have to do this:

- Make a big bad element (a square or a group).
- Put the background to it.
- Move the element on the paper.

I suggest you make a group for this (a g element), since you might add other things later. The "g" element is not defined in raphael, but you can use it with normal js+svg, or you can extend raphael if you feel the urge to do so.

Note 1: Since you said you make a game I feel the need to tell you that I experienced some annoying memory leaks with raphael (something about the paths... can't remember exactly). For example the "polar clock" in the raphael examples had a leak on firefox. I don't necessarily say you'll get the same problem, but I suggest some to take a look at some canvas things before you start it (take a look at three js: http://threejs.org/). The major advantage would be that is made over web gl and is much more optimized, and using the video board also, witch raphael doesn't.

Note 2: Ill put some code in 4-5 hours when I get home if you didn't figure it out by then. Comment if you did pls ;)